# Dereferencing pointer to array of void

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, void, dereference

I am attempting to learn more about C and its arcane hidden powers, and I attempted to make a sample struct containing a pointer to a void, intended to use as array.
EDIT: Important note: This is for raw C code.

Let's say I have this struct.

```
    typedef struct mystruct {
        unsigned char foo;
        unsigned int max;
        enum data_t type;
        void* data;

    } mystruct;
```

I want data to hold *max* of either unsigned chars, unsigned short ints, and unsigned long ints, the data_t enum contains
 values for those 3 cases.

```
    enum Grid_t {gi8, gi16, gi32}; //For 8, 16 and 32 bit uints.
```

Then I have this function that initializes and allocates one of this structs, and is supposed to return a pointer to the new struct.

```
    mystruct* new(unsigned char foo, unsigned int bar, long value) {
        mystruct* new;
        new = malloc(sizeof(mystruct)); //Allocate space for the struct.
        assert(new != NULL);
        new->foo = foo;
        new->max = bar;
        int i;
        switch(type){
            case gi8: default:
                new->data = (unsigned char *)calloc(new->max, sizeof(unsigned char));
                assert(new->data != NULL);
                for(i = 0; i < new->max; i++){
                    *((unsigned char*)new->data + i) = (unsigned char)value;
                    //Can I do anything with the format new->data[n]? I can't seem
                    //to use the [] shortcut to point to members in this case!
                }
            break;
        }
        return new;
    }
```

The compiler returns no warnings, but I am not too sure about this method. Is it a legitimate way to use pointers?

Is there a better way©?

I missed calling it. like mystruct* P; P = new(0,50,1024);

Unions are interesting but not what I wanted. Since I will have to approach every specific case individually anyway, casting seems as good as an union. I specifically wanted to have much larger 8-bit arrays than 32-bits arrays, so an union doesn't seem to help. For that I'd make it just an array of longs :P

Comment: To answer the question in your comments, you can't use [] because it's illegal to dereference a void pointer. If you use a void pointer then you need that switch statement around every single dereference so that you can cast the pointer to the correct type at runtime.

Comment: That was my intention actually.

Comment: your code is only C99, not "raw C". "raw C" is C89. your code doesnt working, in "switch(type)" "type" is undefined.

Comment: @user4 That was a typo when doing the mockup in the post, not in the actual code. And it was spotted before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is `type` supposed to be an argument to the function? (Don't name this function or any variable `new` or any C++ programmer who tries to use it will hunt you down)

If you want to use array indices, you can use a temporary pointer like this:

```
unsigned char *cdata = (unsigned char *)new->data;
cdata[i] = value;
```

I don't really see a problem with your approach. If you expect a particular size (which I think you do given the name `gi8` etc.) I would suggest including `stdint.h` and using the typedefs `uint8_t`, `uint16_t`, and `uint32_t`.

Comment: Sorry, I omitted that when I edited the function for posting. Type is in fact an argument in the full snippet, my bad! I see about the temporary pointer, I will probably like using that approach (makes casting more readable IMO). Just for the record, is there any way to use the foo->bar[0] syntax?

Comment: As other posters have written, a `union` can do this. You could have `ptr_to_mystruct->chars[max-1]`

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot dereference a `void*` pointer, it is forbidden by the C language standard.  You have to cast it to a concrete pointer type before doing so.

As an alternative, depending on your needs, you can also use a `union` in your structure instead of a `void*`:

```
typedef struct mystruct {
    unsigned char foo;
    unsigned int max;
    enum data_t type;
    union {
        unsigned char *uc;
        unsigned short *us;
        unsigned int *ui;
    } data;
} mystruct;
```

At any given time, only one of `data.uc`, `data.us`, or `data.ui` is valid, as they all occupy the same space in memory.  Then, you can use the appropriate member to get at your data array without having to cast from `void*`.

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
typedef struct mystruct 
{
    unsigned char foo;
    unsigned int max;
    enum data_t type;
    union
    {
        unsigned char *chars;
        unsigned short *shortints;
        unsigned long *longints; 
    };
} mystruct;
```

That way, there is no need to cast at all. Just use `data_t` to determine which of the pointers you want to access.

Comment: Yes, this would work too. Dangerous, but C assumes you know what you're doing.

Comment: I read a bit about unions...does it use as much memory as the bigger element (long) or to the biggest allocated element? (so if I assign 255, does it count as long in memory storage?). (I assume the former, but just in case)

Comment: @roger They're all the same size in this case because they're pointers, but in general yes unions take up as much space as their largest member.

Comment: @roger_rales: It uses the size of the largest pointer. Usually, pointers are all the same size. Of course alignment plays a role, but they are probably aligned the same.

Comment: @mkb: probably not more dangerous than casting. There, the compiler also assumes you know what you are doing. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

A pointer is merely an address in the memory space.  You can choose to interpret it however you wish.  Review `union` for more information on how you can interpret the same memory location in multiple ways.

casting between pointer types is common in C and C++, and the use of void* implies that you dont want users to accidentally dereference (dereferencing a void* will cause an error, but dereferencing the same pointer when cast to int* will not)